# Prevent DefaultAntiforgery from logging errors

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, antiforgerytoken

Is there a way to stop DefaultAntiforgery from logging errors? I see it takes an ILoggerFactory as parameter, which is a public type, but I don't know how to set it up since DefaultAntiforgery is internal.

Comment: `Razor Pages` are protected by `antiforgery tokens` by default. You can use the [`IgnoreAntiforgeryToken`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.ignoreantiforgerytokenattribute?view=aspnetcore-6.0) filter to disable XSRF protection for your pages, either by decorating it on individual pages, or by adding the filter globally.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron I don't want to disable it, I want it to stop logging errors to the event log.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think this is a DI issue, but rather a configuration issue. What you want should be possible by [configuring logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/logging?tabs=command-line#configure-logging)

Try something like this in your appsettings.json:

```json
{
  "Logging": {
    // for all logging providers
    "LogLevel": {
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery": "None"
    },
    // or just for the EventLog provider
    "EventLog": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery": "None"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Excellent. I had to use `EventLog` because according to the docs *A specific log provider is not specified, so LogLevel applies to all the enabled logging providers except for the Windows EventLog.*