# DefaultAntiforgery error after new webfarm servers added

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-6.0, antiforgerytoken

I'm running .NET 6 webfarm on 4 web servers that were configured to use a DFS replicated share between the DCs for the File System storage of the Data Protection keystore. Two new web servers were added but the server admins forgot to configure the access to the keystore for a few days. This resulted in the two servers providing users with invalid keys.

```
services.AddDataProtection()
    .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo("{key-store-path}"));
```

This is the error being logged. It is occurring for normal traffic of GET requests and it is filling up the logs.

```
Exception type: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.DefaultAntiforgery.TokenDeserializeException
An exception was thrown while deserializing the token.
Message: The antiforgery token could not be decrypted.

Exception type: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.AntiforgeryValidationException
Stack trace:
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.DefaultAntiforgeryTokenSerializer.Deserialize(String serializedToken)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.DefaultAntiforgery.GetCookieTokenDoesNotThrow(HttpContext httpContext)

Message: The payload was invalid. For more information go to http://aka.ms/dataprotectionwarning

Exception type: System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException
Stack trace:
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Cng.CbcAuthenticatedEncryptor.DecryptImpl(Byte* pbCiphertext, UInt32 cbCiphertext, Byte* pbAdditionalAuthenticatedData, UInt32 cbAdditionalAuthenticatedData)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Cng.Internal.CngAuthenticatedEncryptorBase.Decrypt(ArraySegment`1 ciphertext, ArraySegment`1 additionalAuthenticatedData)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.UnprotectCore(Byte[] protectedData, Boolean allowOperationsOnRevokedKeys, UnprotectStatus& status)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.DangerousUnprotect(Byte[] protectedData, Boolean ignoreRevocationErrors, Boolean& requiresMigration, Boolean& wasRevoked)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.Unprotect(Byte[] protectedData)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.DefaultAntiforgeryTokenSerializer.Deserialize(String serializedToken)
```

Permissions to the keystore were corrected and I changed the Cookie, Form field, and Header names in the AddAntiforgery() call so the application would no longer look at old/invalid values being passed in during validation.

```
services.AddAntiforgery(
    options =>
    {
        options.Cookie.Name = "{customized}";
        options.FormFieldName = "{customized}";
        options.HeaderName = "X-CSRF-TOKEN"; // Was X-XSRF-TOKEN
    });
```

Unfortunately, I am still seeing the same exception for regular traffic, *The payload was invalid.*, in the logs of the application. I can't tell what would causing it. I'm about to add a middleware exception handler to "do nothing" when this exception is seen because the error is filling up the logs or [turn off logging all together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72242049/prevent-defaultantiforgery-from-logging-errors). Does anyone know why I might still be seeing this error? Thanks

Comment: According to this thread, the keys can be held in memory for 2 days (the new ones are probably still using DPAPI keys?):  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34319802/mvc-6-webfarm-the-antiforgery-token-could-not-be-decrypted

Comment: I stopped the app pools when I deployed the Name settings above after the Keystore share access was corrected. Unless I'm misunderstanding, shouldn't this clear the associated memory being discussed there, forcing the application to serve up new key values? I did test the site directly on a new Web Server and verified that the Form field has a populated key value and that a form submission validated the token without an error.

Comment: Seems like that should do it, but maybe restart the server, too.  If none of that helps, I would force all clients to re-login.  They may need a new session.  There are certain clients that can't submit any forms because of this error, correct?  Try troubleshooting with one of them to see if logging out (in some cases would require removing cert) can clear the issue.

Comment: What I believe I'm seeing is this error show up on normal GET request traffic to the website. I have not encountered any users reporting issues with submitting forms.

Comment: That's pretty odd.  You shouldn't be using anti-forgery tokens for GET requests.  (and those shouldn't be "state-changing"...)  Are you using a JS framework's anti-forgery tokens here?

Comment: No, I don't believe so.

Comment: I ask because you are setting the options.HeaderName there.  That's only used if AJAX reads the token and then sends a custom header with that name/value.  However, you don't need anti-forgery tokens for GET requests, and you should never change state using a GET.  If this is being used for GETs, the javascript may read a cookie or a local storage variable.  Those may need to be cleared?

Comment: Ah, that is not in use yet by any AJAX calls. The GET calls I'm referring to above are simply page requests when I look at the log associated with the error.

Comment: I guess every request is going to send the cookie... and since the backend gets it, maybe it tries to decrypt it??  Once the cookie expires it seems like the errors will go away.   Check the expiration date on the cookie to see when that may be.  You may have made things worse by changing the name of the cookie since the old one won't be over-written?  (I'm just taking a wild guess here...)

Comment: Not sure that I follow. Nothing should be looking for the old cookie name since I changed it and with a app recycle, right? The old ones are simply ignored and will expire on their own. This is where my confusion is with what is generating this error. If the key names are all changed, why would something still be looking at an old key name?

Comment: the old cookies will be sent with every request... GET, POST, whatever... since the domain matches the cookie.  I'm just guessing really that the back-end sees that cookie and decides to decrypt it, even though there's no point in doing that.  (but again, just a wild guess)  Not sure why it'd decrypt every cookie it's sent.   You may also want to be sure that each server is using the same version of ASP.NET as there were updates after 2.1 or so?

Comment: I would assume the app ignores the old cookie names, but perhaps not. The two new servers appear to have .NET 6.0.13 while the original servers were created with 6.0.6. I'll have to check the .NET change logs to see if there were any changes to the related processes.